# Confusion trying to take directional direvative of a function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Here's the question that got me a little confused:

> let $z=f(x,y)$  defined by: $z^3 + 3yz-4x=0$ in the neighborhood of point $(1,1,1)$. 
> Find the partial derivative of $f$ in the direction of $(2,-3)$ in the point $(1,1)$

My confusion is: 
I know how to take the directional derivative, both by definition and by using the gradient vector $\nabla f* \hat n$, but here the function isn't like I've always seen where $f(x,y)=x+y ...$, so my question is do I need to do this: $z=\sqrt[3]{4x-3yz}$ and then start solving, or I can just take $\nabla f=(f_x , f_y)=(-4,3z)$ and solve? 
I would appreciate any explanation of why I can or can't do these stuff I explained, thanks in advance!

Comment: 95% certain you just do implicit differentiation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, implicit differetiation: Since $z^3+ 3yz- 4x= 0$, differentiating with respect to x, $3z^2z_x+ 3yz_x- 4= 0$ and, differentiating with rezpect to y, $3z^2z_y+ 3z+ 3yz_y= 0$.  Setting (x,y,z)= (1,1,1), $3z_x+ 3z_x- 4= 0$ and $3z_y+ 3+ 3z_y= 0$.  $6z_x= 4$ so $z_x= 4/6= 2/3$ and $6z_y= -3$ so $z_y= -1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain a little where you are adding the partial derivatives $z_x, z_y$, I've never seen differentiation like this before and not exactly got the idea

Comment: I did NOT, at any point, "add the partial derivatives $z_x$,  $z_y$"!  Please show what you are referring to.

Comment: differentiating with respect to x: $3z^2(z_x) + 3y(z_x)-4 = 0$. (add might have been the wrong word)

Comment: That's the chain rule.  If f is a function of z and z is a function of x the $f_x= f_zz_x$